# Docker: Change port number during runtime

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

```
FROM    openjdk:8-jre-alpine

COPY    --from=builder tmp/target/Application*.jar  app.jar

RUN     mkdir -p /app
ARG     specified_port=8090
ENV     EXPOSED_PORT=$specified_port
EXPOSE  $EXPOSED_PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "app.jar"]
```

And during the runtime how can i change the ports during docker run
server.port to 8092

sample docker run

```
docker run --net="host" -p 8092:8092 -p 9992:9992 4794973497437
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  With your current `docker run` command, you should be able to remove the `--net host` option so Docker port mappings actually work, and then remap the port `-p 8092:8090` using the application's fixed port as the second port number.